# java : Array , How can I use find Distance (distance,name) function and display distance?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

java : Array , How can I use find Distance (distance,name) function and display distance?
java : Array , How can I use find Distance (distance,name) function and display distance?
java : Array , How can I use find Distance (distance,name) function and display distance?

```
package practice;

public class displayDistance 
{   
   /*I'm playing around with Arrays in Java and had this doubt.
     How do I call the  find Distance (distance,name) and display distance .

     5 Requirement are :
     1) Define 2-D Array for distance and populate it. 
     2) ask user for source and destination ( preferably lets use Exception Handling along with JOptionPane prompt .
        e.g. 1st prompt-> From city :  , 2nd prompt->  To city :    
     3)define a city Array 
     4)call function findDistance (distance,name) to find distance and  return it . 
     5)display distance.*/

    public class practice {
        public void main(String[] args) 
        {

          //1. Define 2-D Array for distance and populate it .      
          int [][] distances = { {0,50,100,20},{50,0,70,110},
                               {100,70,0,200},{20,110,200,0} };

          //3. define a city Array          
          String [] names = {"manassas","fairfax","baltimore","centerville"};       

          // calling (invoking)the function         
           findDistance (distances,names);


          // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The distance value is: " + findDistance(distances), "DISTANCE VALUE",
          // JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);     

        }   

     private String findDistance(int[][] distances, String[] names) {                       
         return null;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand it you need a source and destination and calculate the distance between those two, since you already seem to have all the distances in your `distances` array you only need to get the correct number and no need to calculate it yourself. I'm not going to tell you the solution for your homework problem, but your `findDistance` method looks wrong,  unless you want the permutation from all source locations to all destinations. :)

Comment: @Sammy, your code was not well formatted. I have formatted it, but it was asking for some more detail information about your issue. I have just copied your question and paste it. Please give some detail about your issue. It is not so clear.

Comment: Abhijit , what detail you need i will provide you as much as i can !

Comment: question is not clear. 2D array is OK but what actually you need to find from this example. Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Vinod Kumar Kashyap , i need to pass two arrays such as array of distance and array of names to findDistance function also passing from : , to user prompt to this function .

Comment: user need to ask : from what city (source) to what city ( destination) , programs at end it has to find the index of those cities and it gives the number of distance : )

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Demo6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] distances = {{0, 50, 100, 20}, {50, 0, 70, 110},
                {100, 70, 0, 200}, {20, 110, 200, 0}};

        String[] names = {"manassas", "fairfax", "baltimore", "centerville"};

        /* Take two more inputs which are FROM city TO city */
        /* I have taken two default city names below */
        /* And findDistance method should have four arguments */

        findDistance(distances, names, "baltimore", "centerville");
    }

    private static void findDistance(int[][] distances, String[] names, String a, String b) {

        int x = 0, y = 0;

        /*below i am finding the index of the cities 'a' and 'b'*/
        /*below logic works only if both the cities exist  in the array*/
        
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i].equals(a))
                x = i;
            if (names[i].equals(b))
                y = i;
        }
    /*after calculating the index just print their cost from the matrix distance*/
    /*its as simple as that*/
        System.out.println(distances[x][y]);

    }
}
```

Hope it helps. I have explained the code in comments.

Comment: may i know the reason of downvote? I want to know what i did wrong, It will help me in future.

Comment: thank you anupam691997 for help but this is not what i want ,

Comment: @sammy What is it you want then, maybe explain a little more? This answers your question in my option, except @anupam691997 is comparing strings with `==` it seems correct. It obviously isn't a 100% solution to your question, but should help with the main problem.

Comment: @xander thanks for pointing that mistake, corrected it. I still don't get the reason of downvote and what the user wants. but anyway thank you for understanding.

Comment: as you all know its array [4][4]  
user will be asked : from what city (source) to what city ( destination) , once those cities was entered , programs at end it has to find the index of those cities and it gives the number of distance : ) and it display those distances using displayDistance function .

Comment: https://therevisionist.org/software-engineering/java/tutorials/2-dimensional-array/          ->  my question was very similar to this example - (  the following table that lists the distances between cities can be stored using a two-dimensional array named distances.)  all i need using two function to to find and get a distance .